# How to underline label with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my code to underline label in tkinter so when i Enter a name twice i would see both of them and the new name will be in a different line (sorry for bad explanation) so how can underline a label?

```
    window = Tk()
window.geometry("850x550")
first_color=Label(window,bg="#09B683",padx=120,pady=999)
second_color=Label(window,bg="#21FF99",padx=100,pady=999)
third_color=Label(window,bg="#19ff04",padx=1000,pady=11).place(x=0,y=10)
fourth_color=Label(window,bg="#19ff04",text="SCHOOL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM",font=("BOLD",15)).place(x=240,y=15)
first_color.place(x=0,y=50)
second_color.place(x=200,y=50)
def ID_buttons():
    Name_label=Label(window,text="Name",bg="#09B683",font=("Bold",12)).place(x=67,y=70)
    Name_entry=Entry(window,width=20,borderwidth=1)
    Name_entry.place(x=34,y=95)
    Number_label=Label(window,text="Contact Number",bg="#09B683",font=("Bold",12)).place(x=38,y=130)
    Number_entry=Entry(window,width=20,borderwidth=1)
    Number_entry.place(x=34,y=155)
    Email_Label=Label(window,text="Email Address",bg="#09B683",font=("Bold",12)).place(x=38,y=190)
    Email_Entry=Entry(window,width=20,borderwidth=1)
    Email_Entry.place(x=34,y=215)
    Gender_label=Label(window,text="Gender",bg="#09B683",font=("Bold",12)).place(x=63,y=245)
    Gender_Entry=Entry(window,width=20,borderwidth=1)
    Gender_Entry.place(x=34,y=270)
    Date_of_birth_=Label(window,text="Date of Birth",bg="#09B683",font=("Bold",12)).place(x=48,y=295)
    Date_of_birth_entry=Entry(window,width=20,borderwidth=1)
    Date_of_birth_entry.place(x=34,y=323)
    a =440
    def add_records():
        Information_label=Label(window,text=Name_entry.get()).place(x=a,y=400)
        a =-40
    add_record=Button(window,text="Add Record",padx=64,pady=8,command=add_records).place(x=1,y=370)
    ID=Label(window,text="ID     |     Name      |           Email ID                            |  Gender             |  Date Of Birth").place(x=405,y=60)
ID_buttons()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show us what you tried ? Please, provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can build on it to help you.

Comment: Yea I will show you
I Hope that's enough for you to understand
     def add_records():
        Information_label=Label(window,text=Name_entry.get()).place(x=a,y=400)
        a =-40
    add_record=Button(window,text="Add Record",padx=64,pady=8,command=add_records).place(x=1,y=370)

Comment: The goal is not to understand, but to be able to run the code easily so we can test it, and add things to it ;). You can edit your question so everyone can see it when they read it :)

Comment: Oh Ok I'll send you the whole code

Comment: Take a look at my post

Answer (score 3):

It is actually very simple. Just add a parameter font and specify the required parameters of font also. Such as font name, size and special formatting such as underlined text. Check the example below.

```
your_label = Label(window, 
                   text = "Your Text", 
                   font = ("Consolas", 10, "underline")).pack()
```

Comment: Damn I would do anything to get this explanation cuz I wasn't able to find it somewhere else Thank you for your kindess

Comment: No problem. I just made an application with Tkinter so now this is stuck in my head! Haha! Although, in this same way, you can make text bold and italics in case you wanna know!